# Every partially defined isometry can be extended to a isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, isometry

I know that the following theorem holds true:

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, and let $f:S\to \mathbb R^n$ a map such that $d(p,q)=d(f(p),f(q))$ for every $p,q \in S$ (here $d$ is the usual euclidean distance). Suppose that $0 \in S$ and $f(0)=0$. Then $f$ can be extended to an orthogonal transformation of $\mathbb R^n$.

I have two questions:

1. Can someone give me a reference of a proof of this theorem?
2. I believe that the previous theorem holds true also if we change $\mathbb R^n$ with $\mathbb C^n$ and "orthogonal" with "unitary", with nearly the same proof. Does it holds true also in the $ \ell^2$ space? With the same proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Infinite-dimensional case

False. Consider the backward shift operator on $\ell^2$:
$$S^*(x) = (x_2,x_3,\dots)$$
which is an isometry of the subspace $\{x:x_1=0\}$ onto $\ell^2$. It can't be extended further since it's already surjective.

#### Complex case

False. For example, there is no unitary transformation $T:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $T(1)=1$ and $T(i)=-i$. The issue is that as long as Euclidean metric is concerned, $\mathbb{C}^n$ is just $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. But the unitary group $U(n)$ is much smaller than $O(2n)$, due to the $\mathbb{C}$-linearity requirement.

#### Real case

True. A reference is [Theorem 11.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sP6v.png) in *[Embeddings and Extensions in Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=7_DuCAAAQBAJ)* by J.H. Wells and L.R. Williams. Terminological note: they say that a pair of spaces $(X,Y)$ has the isometric extension property if every isometry from a subset of $X$ into $Y$ can be extended to an isometry of $X$ into $Y$.