# Are all isometries of subsets affine?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, orthogonality, isometry

I've found at least two questions that deal with whether isometries are affine,   [Are isometries always linear?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872090/are-isometries-always-linear) and [Should isometries be linear?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570139/should-isometries-be-linear)

However, both of these questions assume we are dealing with entire vector spaces. What if, instead, we have two normed vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with $X\subset V$ and $f:X\rightarrow W$ an isometry (i.e., $\vert\vert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\vert\vert_W=\vert\vert x_1-x_2\vert\vert_V$ for all $x_1,x_2$ in $X$)? Since a general subset $X$ isn't a vector space, the question must be made more precise: is $f$ the restriction of some affine transformation $g:V\rightarrow W$ to $X$? By the Mazur-Ulam theorem, this is equivalent to asking whether $f$ can always be extended to a surjective isometry on all of $V$. If not, what additional conditions have to be met for $f$ to be affine in this sense?

My motivation for asking this is that often we say rigid motions must be given by orthogonal transformations. For example, a rigid cube flying through the air can only rotate. But since the time evolution of the cube is only a map from the cube's initial configuration to its present, saying that such motion must be affine because isometries of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a whole are affine doesn't seem to follow -  I don't care about $\mathbb{R}^3$, I only care about the cube specifically.

Comment: Your motivation is very different from the question you asked. For instance, mapping $(x,y,0)$ to $(x,y)$ is an isometry from a subset of  $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, but it can't be extended to an isometry from all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ since it's already subjective. A better question would be to restrict to the same domain and codomain and probably to really just restrict to just $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard norm, in which case the result is true.

Comment: @CharlieCunningham Silly that I missed that example. Would it prehaps suffice to also require that there exist an isomorphism between $V$ and some subspace of $W$ (so that $W$ is "at least as big")?

Comment: That's not enough. You really need that V is finite dimensional. For instance, consider the map from $\mathbb{\ell}^2$ to $\mathbb{\ell}^2$ given by $(0, a_1, a_2, .... )$ gets sent to $(a_1, a_2, .... )$. Again, this is a surjective isometry, and so can't be extended to a full isometry on the domain, but the domain and codomain are isomorphic.

Comment: @CharlieCunningham Ok, let's make $V$ and $W$ finite-dimensional with some norms. I'd also be happy just to see a proof for the case $V=W=\mathbb{R}^n$ with standard norm, but I am curious to see how general this is.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687436/every-partially-defined-isometry-can-be-extended-to-a-isometry

Comment: Finite dimensional normed vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ are all equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard norm.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!